# asp net web core on IIS : site is inacessible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I want to deploy my project ASP net web core on my LAN.

However, from visual studio I have published the project. I want to deploy on IIS (windows classic (not windows server)). But when I go to site the browser tell : site is inaccessible

Someone has an idea ?

I have tried to follow the Microsoft tutorial and some youtube tutorials but nothing works for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install .Net Core Runtime [Runtime link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)

launch the IIS and change the application pool of the deployed application and set it to No Manage Code

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Which version should I install ?

Comment: It depends on the version of .net core you are working with. Kindly share the version of .net core . so as to give you a detailed walkthrough

Comment: Install Runtime & Hosting Bundle 2.0.6 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0   and ensure 64bit is installed.

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is always here.
If I don't defined a hostname application I have an error 500
else I have an error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Try this link if it will help solve the error : https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-error-code-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-problem/

Comment: On chrome or firefox, the problem is the same.
I think I have made sth bad in my IIS configuration or in my project publish step